# Apply JavaScript syntax highlighting for [vscode-settings]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Questions about settings in Visual Studio Code naturally almost always include JSON snippets, but people rarely bother to add explicit language hints. It doesn't seem appropriate to tag these questions with [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json).

The only issue here is that the snippets sometimes also include *comments*, which is normally not valid in JSON files, but *is* allowed in Visual Studio Code's `settings.json` format (the "language mode" for those files is in fact *"JSON with Comments"*). However, this [can easily be worked around by using JavaScript instead of JSON highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29972553/2631715).

Could JavaScript syntax highlighting be applied by default for [vscode-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode-settings)?

Comment: Done. Ping me if there are any further issues with this change.